# MSAL 3.x GetAuthorizationRequestUrlParameterBuilder returns wrong datatype

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication

According to the reference for [ConfidentialClientApplication.GetAuthorizationRequestUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplication.getauthorizationrequesturl?view=azure-dotnet), the method

> Computes the URL of the authorization request letting the user sign-in and consent to the application accessing specific scopes in the user's name. The URL targets the /authorize endpoint of the authority configured in the application.

So, I should be able to get the authorization request URL with the code like the following:

```
string[] graphScopes = { "Files.Read.All", "User.Read" };

ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder clientBuilder = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(Settings.AzureADClientId);
ConfidentialClientApplication clientApp = (ConfidentialClientApplication)clientBuilder.Build();

var urlBuilder = clientApp.GetAuthorizationRequestUrl(graphScopes);
urlBuilder.WithRedirectUri(loginRedirectUri.ToString());
urlBuilder.WithAuthority(Settings.AzureADAuthority);
var authUrl = await urlBuilder.ExecuteAsync();
authUrl. ????
```

But the `GetAuthorizationRequestUrlParameterBuilder.ExecuteAsync()` method returns an `AuthorizationResult` which is not a URL and has no property with a URL in it.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong, or explain how to actually get the authorization request URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the method `ExecuteAsync()` that returns `Uri` is not the parameterless one:

```
public Task<Uri> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

So, maybe what you want to do is:

```
var authUrl = await urlBuilder.ExecuteAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
```

The bug got fixed on MSAL v4: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/msal-net-4

Answer (score 3):

Although @TiagoBrenck is correct, this is a bug and I have logged https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/1193

In terms of coding style, I'd write the code more like this:

```cs
  string[] graphScopes = { "Files.Read.All", "User.Read" };

  IConfidentialClientApplication cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("<client_id>").Build();

  Uri url = await cca.GetAuthorizationRequestUrl(graphScopes)
                 .WithRedirectUri("some_uri")
                 .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdAndPersonalMicrosoftAccount)
                 .ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None)
                 .ConfigureAwait(false);
```